# AdMob revenue and alternatives : Impression vs Clicks

Tags: android, admob

I actually use AdMob for my Android apps.

For the moment I have zero revenue even if I'm approaching 1000 impressions. So I conclude that AdMob is based on CPC ([cost per Click](https://www.bloggermafia.online/2019/09/Admob-Revenue.html)) system (because I have indeed no click).

- Is it always the case ? Or does AdMob use also cost per impression system sometimes ? If yes, can we choose the use rather this cost per impression system ?
- [Otherwise, is there any alternative ads network that pays you entirely, or partially, with cost per impression ?](https://www.bloggermafia.online/2019/09/Admob-Revenue.html)

**Edit** :

[For the moment here is what I found :](https://www.bloggermafia.online/2019/09/Admob-Revenue.html)

- **AdMob** -> CPC : (from my own experience)
- **JumpTap** -> CPC from [this page](http://www.jumptap.com/sign-up/) : "*Promote your business with pay-per-click advertising*"
- **inMobi** -> not precised
- **mmedia** -> CPM, CPC and CPA from [this page](http://mmedia.com/help-center/monetize/reporting-performance/reporting/) : "*Your earnings metric or effective CPM. Because we offer a variety of campaigns on our network including CPM (cost per thousand impressions), CPC (cost per click) and CPA (cost per action), eCPM provides a consistent way to track your earnings for every ad shown.*"

  But I have no idea if we can choose our preferred system here...
- **MobFox** : CPC and CPM from [this page](http://www.mobfox.com/publisher-ecpmcontrol) : They mention a "*2$ per thousand*" in their exemple. But here again, no idea if we have control over which system is used or if we're forced to be pay by a CPC system.

I think indeed that using different networks can be very interesting (for example through Mediation in adMob).

Also be careful with the "CPM" or "CPI" : Sometimes Networks mention cost per impression (CPI) but in fact they just pay you with CPC and evaluate a CPI by doing simply *Nb of impression / Nb of click*. Of course in this case the CPI is only an indicator but doesn't guarantee any revenue.

Comment: AdMob Cost-per-thousand-impressions (CPM) https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3436338?hl=en

Comment: explanation of how admob works https://stackoverflow.com/a/55784330/10304059

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think AdMob is CPC based and you can't earn any money from impressions in any way.
Have a look at mMedia (http://mmedia.com/) and inMobi which are also supported with the AdMob SDK using the mediation mode: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/mediation/

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm looking to the other networks but I don't know why they don't say on their website : "We pay you per click" or "We pay you per impression". For example on mmedia.com they say "Because we offer a variety of campaigns on our network including CPM (cost per thousand impressions), CPC (cost per click) and CPA (cost per action), eCPM provides a consistent way to track your earnings".But nowhere we know if there's the possibility to choose between these different systems. On the inMobi website, I haven't found any information concerning the system used (have I missed it ?)

Comment: Did you find a cost per impression advertising network? I'm in the same spot as you