# AdMob Earnings - How are they calculated

Tags: admob

How are AdMob Earnings calculated? Is it dependent on the number of clicks alone? Or is it dependent on the ads that are shown? Or a combination of both?

One day I have 11 clicks that earned me $0.12 and the next day I have 14 clicks that earned me $0.51 and then one day I just earn $0.07 for 11 clicks.

Here is the screenshot of my earnings from AdMob...

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It also depends on the impression that it makes, if the ads are show many times and u get 11 clicks u get less money
if the ads are displayed less time and you get 11 clicks u get more money.
Also it got more of complex process
Hope you understand
try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570139/admob-revenue-and-alternatives-impression-vs-clicks) it may have what you are searching.

Comment: Do you get paid only by clicks but also impressions as well=

Comment: impression decides how much money you will get per click. less impression high click will earn more than lots of impression and less click.

Answer (score 25):

The short is, Google has an auction system for their ads. The more you are willing to pay for them, the more they will show up in prime real estate. What this means to you is that the cost per click is dependent on the ad, which can change wildly from day to day.