# Not able to link my android app in admob

Tags: android, admob

I published an android app two days back. It is there in play store.

Now I am trying to link my app in admob, it says **No application found. Please refine your query.**

Please provide some suggestions.
Should I wait more or is there any issue?

Comment: Make sure you are following [steps](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/1620109?hl=en) and I think you should wait 1 more day. It may take time in approving app and make it global.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must check if you set the AdMob configuration correctly and in mostly you do that, 
then you just have to wait, because i faced this issue and i was forced to waiting for one week to be able to link my application, AdMob sometimes needs more than two days to be able to link your application.
try everyday to check if you can link your application

Comment: thanks for response. Few hours later I got a mail from Google, stating ur account is disabled for invalid clicks. I am not sure about it. Can you suggest how google tracks clicks from other users who may intentionally clicks adds multiple times?

Comment: actually the mail that you are got from Google i don't know about what it's mean, but for your questions about tracks clicks from other, i think you can take a look for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845703/admob-earnings-how-are-they-calculated