# AdMob Network Report Guidance

Tags: admob, terminology, ads, definition

I've just started to use AdMob in my apps, and I am a little unsure on the different terms (such as "Requests", "Impressions", etc.) and what they mean in the Network Report. For example:

[image]

Although I have found some information regarding what some of these terms mean, a complete guide for it would be more useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Guide to AdMob terms:

**Requests**
These are the number of times your app *requests* to show an ad *(do not confuse with 'Impressions')*. These will depend on the number of users your app has and the number of times the ad is refreshed.

**Impressions**
Impressions are the number of times an individual ad is *displayed* on your app. Note that it is possible to have many requests for your ad, but there may not be any advertisements available to show resulting in lower impressions.

**Fill rate**
This is a percentage representing how often ads are shown (i.e. how often they are 'filled'). In other words, it is the number of impressions divided by the number of requests. For example, if your app makes 50 ad requests and 50 impressions, it means that your ad is shown 50 times out of the 50 times (i.e. 100%) it has requested ads. However, if you have 5 impressions but 35 requests, your fill rate will be 5/35 (~14.29%). You can calculate this simply by using the following formula:
*Impressions ÷ Requests × 100*

**Clicks**
This is quite self-explanatory: it is the total number of times that users click on ads shown in your app.

**Impression CTR**
'CTR' is an abbreviation for 'Click-through rate'. Impression CTR is the percentage representing how often ads on your app are clicked. Say I have 2 clicks and 46 impressions, my Impression CTR will be about 3.03%. It can be calculated using the following formula:
*Clicks ÷ Impressions × 100*
So in my example, 2 divided by 46, then multiplied by 100 would give me ~3.03 which is my Impression CTR.

**Request RPM**
'RPM' stands for 'Revenue per mille' or 'Revenue per 1,000' (*mille* means *a thousand* in Latin). In this case, we are referring to the revenue per 1,000 requests. As far as I know, this can be subject to change depending on various factors such as the advertisements.

**Impression RPM**
Impression RPM refers to the revenue per 1,000 impressions. Much like *Request RPM*, Impression RPM is a representation of the estimated earnings you would receive for every 1,000 impressions. According to the AdMob Help Page, "*it's calculated by dividing your estimated earnings by the number of page views, impressions or queries that you received, then multiplying by 1000*". As with *Request RPM*, this value is subject to change.

**Estimated Earnings**
This is your estimated balance for the time/date period selected (in the image posted in your question, the time/date period can be seen just under the top-right corner in the image). Every month, your estimated earnings are verified for accuracy, so it is subject to change, as with *RPM*. There is no easy way to calculate this figure, because it depends on many different factors. The way AdMob works is similar to an auction system (*as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14845821/4230345) explains*). The more money other developers pay for advertising, the more likely it is that they will show up in apps. This means that the revenue you receive per click depends on the ad, and can vary drastically.