# How AdMob earnings are calculated?

Tags: admob

I am a bit confused about how AdMob revenues  are calculated. I'd like to use the following screenshot as an example:

[image]

I had some questions :

- How the cost per click  is calculated? Because in this example it's 1.52€, but some days it's something like 0.05-0.10€.
- Also, if I follow what's indicated here, should I earn 1,52€ for the click, and ~0.68€ for every 1000 impression? (so something around 1.50-1.60€)

Thank your for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So your question is

> I am a bit confused about how AdMob revenues are calculated

let me answer this.

**Short answer**

Admob earning are directly depend on click , the more the click will the more will be revenue . It also depends on the impression that it makes, if the ads are show many times and u get only one clicks you get less money. If the ads are displayed few times and you get one clicks you get more money.

,ie,

If your Impressions or show rate is large but Clicks is low then you will get low revenue.

and

If your Impressions or show rate is same (or good) as Clicks  then you will get high revenue.

**Long answer**

*Estimated earnings*

Your earnings accrued so far. This amount is an estimate that is subject to change when your earnings are verified for accuracy at the end of every month.

*Total impressions*

The total number of ads shown to users across all of your ad units and apps through mediation. Includes a period-over-period comparison.

*Match rate*

The percentage of requests that were successfully sent to an ad network in the mediation chain. It's calculated by dividing matched requests by successful ad network requests:

Matched requests / Successful ad network requests

- eCPM (RPM)*

**eCPM and RPM are same**

Effective cost per thousand impressions.

An estimate of the revenue that you receive for every thousand ad impressions. eCPM is calculated as (Total Earnings / Impressions) x 1000.

Formula: eCPM = ( Estimated earnings / # of impressions ) * 1000

*Clicks*

The total number of times users click ads shown in your app.

sources:-

[medium blog](https://medium.com/infancyit/understanding-admob-network-51fb92f3a199)

Answer (score 2):

**How is calculated the cost per click? Because in this example it's 1.52€, but some days it's something like 0.05-0.10€.**

- Every country has a different payout set to them. A user from the United States will give you more revenue for a click than a user from a 3rd world country.

**Also, if I follow what's indicated here, should I earn 1,52€ for the click, and ~0.68€ for every 1000 impression? (so something around 1.50-1.60€)**

- You do not get paid for your impressions but only per click. RPM is just an average of how much money you made so far from your clicks, per 1000 views/impressions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I chose @jsRook answer as the accepted one as it was a bit more informative, but yours was also very useful.